# Using Intl.NumberFormat with 'de' locale and 'percent' style

Tags: javascript, firefox, localization, number-formatting

I Tried to use Intl.NumberFormat object to format my user inputs. 
In my javascript project I Create component and tried to use it as below;

```
const simpleFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {style: 'percent'});

simpleFormat.format(12345678)
```

It gives me result as **123.456.78%** When I am expecting **123.456,78%**
comma , and dot . separators working fine with currency style for same locale. But it seems not working with 'percent' mode. Does anyone has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, formatting as a percent **12345678** yields a string of **1.234.567.800%** *not "123.456.78%"* and that is because, simply, the decimal 12345678 is multiplied by 100 to get the percentage value (such that the decimal 1 is equal to 100%).

Another problem you'll have is that the *percent* style will not use any decimals by default, so you'll need to use the `maximumFractionDigits` option so that it uses them if needed.

With all that, if you wanted to **23.456,78%** you would need:

```js
const simpleFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'percent',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});
let perc = simpleFormat.format(1234.5678);
console.log(perc);
```

Comment: Yes. Got it now. Thanks @rgthree